# JSON Parsing with jq if-then-else issues

Tags: json, bash, jq

I am writing a script that will parse a JSON file and extract out some docker container names and the servers that they are running on.  I then need to do some other things in bash with the info I get.  I am new to using `jq` but here is what I have gotten so far.

I run the following:

```
cat env.json | jq '[.env.service.config | .[] | {dockerContainerName:.dockerConfig.dockerImageName,servers:[.allocation[].serverName]}]'
```

This gives me an output of:

```
[
  {
    "dockerContainerName": null,
    "servers": []
  },
  {
    "dockerContainerName": "my_awesome_container",
    "servers": [
      "serverX01",
      "serverX02"
    ]
  },
...
...
]
```

As you can see from the result some of the service configs do not have a dockerConfig.dockerImageName.  I need to limit what comes back to filter out the ones that do not have a dockerConfig.  I have tried using an if-then-else but can't seem to get it to work correctly.

Any ideas out there?

Comment: Can you provide the complete `JSON`? and provide the exact output you need out of that? the current information is insufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`select`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#select(boolean_expression)) to restrict the content of the array to objects whose `dockerContainerName` differs from `null` :

```
jq '.[] | select(.dockerContainerName != null)' <<EOF
[
  {
    "dockerContainerName": null,
    "servers": []
  },
  {
    "dockerContainerName": "my_awesome_container",
    "servers": [
      "serverX01",
      "serverX02"
    ]
  }
]
EOF

{
  "dockerContainerName": "my_awesome_container",
  "servers": [
    "serverX01",
    "serverX02"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  I was  able to modify my jq command to the following and get it filtered out using the select you suggested!

`cat env.json | jq '[.env.service.config | .[] | {dockerContainerName:.dockerConfig.dockerImageName,servers:[.allocation[].serverName]} | select(.dockerContainerName != null)]'`

Comment: @pricecreations nice, but I think you could afford to `select` the config before creating your own item : `jq '[.env.service.config[] | select(.dockerConfig.dockerImageName != null) | {dockerContainerName: .dockerConfig.dockerImageName, servers:[‌​.allocation[].server‌​Name]} ]`

Comment: Good call!  That worked and improved the performance as well.

Comment: This isn't Python :) The triple quotes are just interpreted as a pair of empty strings concatenated to the start and end of the single-quoted string in the middle.

Comment: @chepner thanks, I've been using `"""` and `'''` in `bash` for longer than I'd like to admit !